# How do you you remove hyperlink to lookup fields in list form?

Tags: list-form

I'm referring to the box displayed on the right hand of a list which by default displays a lookup field as a hyperlink.I understand ways around that within list views, but I also want to remove the hyperlink in the list form.

Is there a way to display lookup field only as text when it is not necessary to link to the list or field?

Team site, classic template, modern experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern experience is a problem. As you said, you can customize modern views, but there is currently no way to customize modern forms. Either switch the list to classic experience, in which case you can do what you want via Client-side Rendering, or learn to live with it as is for now.

Comment: Just to clarify, no way to customize modern forms right now, other than power apps? I am not familiar enough with power apps yet to use it, but just wanted to clarify whether that would be considered an option for this problem.

Comment: Yes, that's correct of course. And using power apps just to remove the hyperlinks on lookups might be just a tad overkill, but I'm not judging ;)